# Newtonsoft deserialization adds nulls to list

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm simply trying deserialize some JSON from a file into a list of objects, using the Newtonsoft JSON library in C#. Here are the contents of the *MeetingFile.txt* file:

```
[
  {
    "People": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Malcolm",
        "LastName": "Reynolds"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Hoban",
        "LastName": "Washburne"
      }
    ],
    "PairDate": "1/14/2016"
  }
]
```

And here's the code for deserializing the object graph:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\MeetingFile.txt"))
{
    var fileContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var meetingHistory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PairHistoryItem>>(fileContents);
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(meetingHistory);
    return meetingHistory;
}
```

And the classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public readonly string FirstName;
    public readonly string LastName;
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    public List<IPairHistoryItem> PairHistory;

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}

public class PairHistoryItem
{
    public List<Person> People { get; }
    public DateTime PairDate { get; }

    public PairHistoryItem(Person person1, Person person2, DateTime pairDate)
    {
        People = new List<Person> {person1, person2};
        PairDate = pairDate;
    }
}
```

But for whatever reason, this is what's contained in the ***serialized*** variable in my deserialization code:

```
[
  {
    "People": [
      null,
      null,
      {
        "FirstName": "Malcolm",
        "LastName": "Reynolds",
        "PairHistory": null,
        "FullName": "Malcolm Reynolds"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Hoban",
        "LastName": "Washburne",
        "PairHistory": null,
        "FullName": "Hoban Washburne"
      }
    ],
    "PairDate": "2016-01-14T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Where do the nulls at the beginning of the list come from? As far as I can tell, the JSON in my file is formatted properly. Am I missing some setting for the JSON Converter?

Comment: Those RO fields cant be set, in Debug drill into `meetingHistory` and the names will already be null: i.stack.imgur.com/Gud9U.jpg   Naturally, when you re-serialize it, it will still be null.  The json also doesnt have anything relating to `PairHistory` in the person class.

Comment: Well, the weird thing was that I had two null objects along with correctly populated objects, as described above. So it wasn't really the readonly properties as much as it was the constructor. @Nikolai Samteladze seems to be on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nikolai Samteladze summed up the cause of the issue perfectly.  Another possible solution, other than changing your constructor, is to configure Json.Net to replace the existing list during deserialization rather than reusing it.  To do this, you can set the [`ObjectCreationHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) setting to `Replace` (the default is `Auto`):

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;

var meetingHistory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PairHistoryItem>>(fileContents, settings);
```

However, in order for this to work properly you would also need to add a private setter for the `People` property in your `PairHistoryItem` class and mark it with a `[JsonProperty]` attribute so that Json.Net can "see" it:

```
public class PairHistoryItem
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<Person> People { get; private set; }
    public DateTime PairDate { get; }

    public PairHistoryItem(Person person1, Person person2, DateTime pairDate)
    {
        People = new List<Person> {person1, person2};
        PairDate = pairDate;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zs5GI1

Answer (score 4):

The problems is caused by the way constructors are defined in `PairHistoryItem` class. Specifically, the fact that your ONLY constructor populates `People` list with 2 objects.

From what I understand, `JsonConvert.Deserialize` first creates an object before populating it with data. So, first, `JsonConvert.Deserialize` creates a `PairHistoryItem` instance by calling your constructor and providing `null` as arguments. Then it adds 2 `Person` instances that it deserialized. Thus, you end up with 4 elements in `People` list: 2 x `null` and 2 x `Person`.

The easiest solution would be to just add a default constructor to your `PairHistoryItem` class.

```
public PairHistoryItem
{
    People = new List<Person>();
}
```

Comment: This was definitely the problem. The solution was basically what you suggested: 

        public PairHistoryItem(List<Person> people, DateTime pairDate)
        {
            People = people;
            PairDate = pairDate;
        }
I can't have a default constructor without the properties having associated sets for the deserializer to populate the properties with. Right now, I kinda wanted them to be get only and treat the object as immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify value for [`NullValueHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) to Ignore.

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore  };
```

Please note if you use custom Serializer you have to handle this explicitly.

Comment: I think that would help with `PairHistory` properties being `null`, but won't remove these extra `null` in `People` list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that - all items contained nulls.
Then I noticed that forgotted to add attributes! Like [JsonProperty] and so on. May be you are as inattentive as I and it will help you!